# Problems with bias , variance and mse calculation in the California Housing Data

Tags: r

I am trying to analyse the bias, variance and the MSE for linear regression, polynomial regression, regression trees, bagging and random forest for the California Housing Data.
But I am facing issues with the values of Bias and Variance as they don't seem reasonable to me. So I don't know where my mistake lies.
I tried changing the calculations for the bias and variance but the results are all not reasonable. Is it possible to calculate them for a given dataset but only the MSE?

> ```
> summary(housing)
> library(caret)
> library(RColorBrewer)
> library(dplyr)
> library(tibble)
> library(tree)
> library(rpart)
>
> housing <- na.omit(housing)
> str(housing)
>
> dummy_variables <- model.matrix(~ ocean_proximity - 1, data = housing)
> colnames(dummy_variables) <- c("NEAR BAY", "INLAND", "NEAR OCEAN", "<1H OCEAN", "ISLAND")
>
> housing <- housing %>%
> select(-ocean_proximity) %>%
> cbind(dummy_variables)
> View(housing)
> ```
>
> Step 1: Remove the "median_house_value" column
>
> ```
> set.seed(123)
> ```

```
# Determine the number of samples
n_samples <- nrow(housing)
n_samples
# Create a vector of random indices for the training set
split <- n_samples/2
train <- sample(x = 1:n_samples, size = split)

# Split the data into training and test sets
trainData <- housing[train, ]
testData <- housing[-train, ]
lm_model <- lm(logmedv ~ ., data = trainData)
lm_pred <- predict(lm_model, newdata = testData)
# Actual values
test_actual <- testData$logmedv

squared_bias_lm <- mean(lm_pred - test_actual)^2
# Calculate variance
variance_lm <- mean((lm_pred - mean(lm_pred))^2)

# Calculate test MSE
mse_lm <- mean((test_actual-lm_pred)^2)
```

other models not included for now

Comment: Hi Marie! Welcome. Would you be able to spell out *why* the bias and variance don't seem right to you. Is it clear that they aren't just normal values? What do you expect the values to be (roughly), and what did you get?

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for your reply! Yes, sure! So first of all, they don't seem right to me as one can decompose the MSE for a given point x_0 into the Bias(\hatf{_x_0})^2 , the Var(\hatf{_x_0}) and the Var(\epsilon). So my MSE value for the linear regression in this example was 0.1087198. The two metric bias and variance must be lower but not exactly equal to the MSE as I cannot measure the var(\epsilon). But my variance value is 0.2178148 and my bias value 2.3248e-06. The variance value in itself cannot hold as it is larger than the MSE.